# Responsive navigation 'max-height' issue (CSS3 transition)

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I want to create a responsive navigation with a 'slide down' effect. I don't want to use jQuery's `.slideDown()` or `.slideToggle()` but only CSS3 transitions. The only way i'm aware of is using `max-height` to mimic this effect.

So this is more or less the current HTML / CSS code I'm using for the navigation: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tJLHo

**There are two issues with this navigation:**

1. At the moment I'm using `min-width` to reset `max-height: 0` in my media query. Otherwise you won't see a navigation at all for larger screens.

   ```
   // 'min-width' media query
   .nav__list {
       min-height: 500px; 
       /* Is there any better way to reset max-height without using a px value? */
   }
   ```

   This doesn't seem to be right and I'm looking for a solution like `min-height: auto;` or `max-height: auto;`. But this doesn't seem to work for me.
2. I want to set `max-height` to the height of my mobile navigation via jQuery. If I set it to a very large pixel value (as per http://davidwalsh.name/css-slide) I always have a delay when closing the navigation. So I tried something like this:

   ```
   $navIcon.on('click', function() {
       var crtHeight = $navList.height();
       alert('Height: ' + crtHeight); // -> 0
       $navList
           //.css('max-height', crtHeight)
           .toggleClass('nav__list--active');
   });
   ```

   But unfortunately i cant get the height of the my navigation, because it is set to `max-height: 0` (if it's closed). I need something like `$el.heightIgnoreMaxHeight();` :)

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for a solution that avoids the height of your navigation altogether. This way you'll always get a valid result for `$.fn.height()` on your navigation and you avoid known problems (jittering, `height: auto` limitation, etc.) with animated element dimensions.

A viable option for your use case would be e.g. `transform: translateY()`.

**Note**: The examples and the fiddle include the `-webkit-` prefixes only.

For the `hidden` state and the transition:

```
.nav__list {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  ...
}
```

For both `visible` states:

```
.nav__list--active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
}

...

@media only all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .nav__list {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

This implies some additional 'clean up' styling on `.nav`. See it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/b24Ft/1/

Comment: Thanks, that could be an option for me. Is there any way to avoid these strange transition effects if you resize the window while the navigation is 'not open'? Could I just apply the `transition: transform ...` styles to my `.nav__list` if you click on the button and remove it after the transition ends? Or is there a better option?

Comment: Avoiding the transitions kicking in when media queries are applied can be done by: 1. Setting no transition by default on the element, 2. Toggling an 'in' and an 'out' class that both sport a transition, 3. Removing the class that corresponds to the default state (here: 'out') after `transitionEnd`. Check out the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b24Ft/1/

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a good CSS only solution to this, if the height is not known.  What I do is use jQuery to set the height.  I can achieve this by using `scrollHeight` which will return me the correct height even if the element is set to height 0.

**Example**

```
$navIcon.on('click', function() {
    var crtHeight = $navList[0].scrollHeight;

    $navList
    //.css('max-height', crtHeight)
    .toggleClass('nav__list--active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, `el.scrollHeight` seems to solve my second problem. Any suggestions for resetting `max-height` (if the navigation is collapsed) for larger screens? Is there anything similar to `max-height: auto`?